# Default way of executing code in Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell, default

In the following generalized code:

```
nat = [1..xmax]
xmax = *insert arbitrary Integral value here*   

setA = [2*x | x <- nat]
setB = [3*x | x <- nat]

setC = [4*x | x <- nat]
setD = [5*x | x <- nat]

setOne = setA `f` setB
setTwo = setC `f` setD

setAll = setOne ++ setTwo

setAllSorted = quicksort setAll
```

(please note that 'f' stands for a function of type

```
f :: Integral a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

that is not simply ++)

how does Haskell handle attempting to print setAllSorted?

does it get the values for setA and setB, compute setOne and then only keep the values for setOne in memory (before computing everything else)?

Or does Haskell keep everything in memory until having gotten the value for setAllSorted?

If the latter is the case then how would I specify (using main, do functions and all that other IO stuff) that it do the former instead?

Can I tell the program in which order to compute and garbage collect? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: Haskell does not define how your code is executed at all, only what the result must be; this question is inherently implementation-specific.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The head of `setAllSorted` is necessarily less-than-or-equal to every element in the tail.  Therefore, in order to determine the head, all of `setOne` and `setTwo` must be computed.  Furthermore, since all of the sets are constant applicative forms, I believe they will not be garbage collected after being computed.  The numbers themselves will likely be shared between the sets, but the cons nodes that glue them together will likely not be (your luck with some will depend upon the definition of `f`).

Comment: Even though they are CAFs, they can be collected if the compiler can determine that they are not referenced anymore after printing. If the program is `main = print setAllSorted`, there's a good chance that GHC (with optimisations) will garbage collect the parts that aren't needed anymore. That's only a constant factor reduction of peak memory, however.

Comment: does "constant factor" mean it will give a bigger reduction for bigger amounts of data? That is, does it mean the peak memory reduction is directly proportional to the amount of data computed and therefore garbage collected?

Answer (score 7):

Due to laziness, Haskell evaluates things on-demand. You can think of the printing done at the end as "pulling" elements from the list `setAllSorted`, and that might pull other things with it.

That is, running this code it goes something like this:

1. Printing first evaluates the first element of `setAllSorted`.
2. Since this comes from a sorting procedure, it will require all the elements of `setAll` to be evaluated. (Since the smallest element could be the last one).
3. Evaluating the first element of `setAll` requires evaluating the first element of `setOne`.
4. Evaluating the first element of `setOne` depends on how `f` is implemented. It might require all or none of `setA` and `setB` to be evaluated.
5. After we're done printing the first element of `setAllSorted`, `setAll` will have been fully evaluated. There are no more references to `setOne`, `setTwo` and the smaller sets, so all of these are by now eligible for garbage collection. The first element of `setAllSorted` can also be reclaimed.

So in theory, this code will keep `setAll` in memory most of the time, while `setAllSorted`, `setOne` and `setTwo` will likely only occupy a constant amount of space at any time. Depending on the implementation of `f`, the same may be true for the smaller sets.